# WebDriver - Element is not Clickable Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using WebDriver on Chrome and I am getting the following error when clicking an element:

```
Clicking locator: //div[@id='tabContainer']/ul/li[3]/a/div   Element
> is not clickable at point (170, 127). Other element would receive the
> click: <ul style="left: 5px; top: 25px; display: block;"
> class="jdm_events">...</ul> (WARNING: The server did not provide any
> stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 32 milliseconds
> Build info: version: '2.29.0', revision: '58258c3', time: '2013-01-17
> 22:46:35' System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch:
> 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_11' Session ID:
> 740bb830a8add9463c23d4461c99acc9 Driver info:
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP,
> chrome.chromedriverVersion=26.0.1383.0, acceptSslCerts=false,
> javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, rotatable=false,
> locationContextEnabled=false, version=25.0.1364.152,
> cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
> browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
> nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
> takesScreenshot=true}]
```

This is only happening when running multiple tests concurrently through Grid2 using the .NET bindings for WebDriver.

I usually get around 2 test failures out of 20 on each run, but a test that fails one time may run correctly the next.

I am wondering if this is a known issue with Chrome driver, or if there is something that needs to be added to my click method to handle whatever is causing this.

Here is a sample of the code the element to be click lies in:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top">
  <a href="#fundingTab" title="">
    <div class="tab" style="float: left; padding: 0.5em 1em">
     <span style="overflow: visible;">Funding</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is generally when something is in the way of what you are trying to click (i.e what you have found is behind another element)...so what is exactly shown when this error is hit? If this is on a server that you cannot get desktop access to, have your tests take a screenshot on failure (wrap it in a try/catch)

Comment: I captured screenshots in the catch block, and it appears that a dropdown menu that is in the upper left corner is open, 'blocking' some elements.  I'm assuming that Chromedriver defaults the mouse position to here and the hover is opening that menu.  However, I have not found a way to disable this hover event from occurring.

Comment: I have experienced myself the same problem as described from your comment Andrew (i.e. hover over a menu-blocks element)..How are you locating your element using css or using Xpath? I was looking at the error message that you posted here and I couldn't figure it out as your element has the form of xpath but has some div tags behind as well! //div[@id='tabContainer']/ul/li[3]/a/div..I would highly recommend to try locating purely with CSS locator (are you using firebug by the way?)

Answer (score 0):

Because it happens only when you run multiple tests (locally or in some CI mechanism), it could happen also because of an end of a **previous test end state**, which affect the next test.
For example:
In test 1, come component added to the main page. test executed. component removed.
In test 2, the component still appear on the page, which can affect the test.

So, in your case, consider the option that the open menu is like this not because the hovering, but because it got open in the previous test.

Hope it helps.

P.S. And regarding changing of mouse initial position - i found this answer, maybe it could assist you: [How can I reset the Selenium mouse cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606308/how-can-i-reset-the-selenium-mouse-cursor-position)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Olark chat feature after it was added to our site.  In that case, I setup the tests to automatically call the disable API on olark before doing any individual testing after the page loads.

It does slow down testing a little, but it solved the problem.  Perhaps you could inject some javascript to hide the menu after the page loads.  This assumes you don't need to test that menu.