# How can I reset the Selenium mouse cursor position?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a javascript web app with some behavior depending on mouse over using Selenium2 WebDriver C# API. I have an extension method that performs a hover on a web element to keep code DRY.

```
public static void Hover(this IWebElement webElement, IWebDriver driver)
{
    new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(webElement).Perform();
}
```

Now I want a method that "resets" the mouse position to some natural default value independent of element.  I call this in TearDown() to keep the driver in a known state after tests. The best I could come up with is

```
public static void ResetMouseCursor(IWebDriver driver)
{
    new Actions(driver).MoveByOffset(-9999, -9999).Perform();
}
```

Which just put's the browser in no-man's land.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A DOM agnostic method seems like a bad idea. 
 The above code completely tanked in Firefox driver for "going outside of document" exception.

The best thing which I could come up with, is to set the mouse cursor to the (0,0) position of the most root element on the page or (which in my case is an IFrame holding the single page javascript app) and use inheritance to do the initialization. In C# driver this is.

```
public class RootFrame
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#root-id")]
    private IWebElement vfrFrame;
    protected IWebDriver driver;

    public VfrElement(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void ResetMouseCursor()
    {
        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(vfrFrame, 0, 0).Perform();
    }
}
```

Everything in the frame can just inherinant the class and get access to the method.